# Initialize UIButton with parameters

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to initialize a subclass of `UIButton` with parameters, however I am getting a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error in my `init(create: ; coder:)` method:

```
class DayButton: UIButton {


    var forCreateView: Bool

    init(create: Bool? = false, coder: NSCoder? = nil){
        self.forCreateView = create!
        super.init(coder: coder!)  //EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
    }

    convenience required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(create: Bool(), coder: aDecoder) //most definitely not right
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift its "better" to try to bypass custom subclass initiation as good as possible <- my opinion don't listen to it... :-)

For guys that anyway love it... You could create a convenience initializer, init your stuff here and call a designated initializer, to init the superclass also... below is an example...

```
class DayButton: UIButton {

    var forCreateView: Bool = false

    convenience init (forCreateView: Bool) {
        self.init()
        self.forCreateView = forCreateView
    }

}

let myButton: UIButton = DayButton(forCreateView: false) //Usage
```

Comment: Thank you! But why don't you like custom subclass initiation? Also how come I don't have to call `required init(coder: NSCoder)` in the initialization above?

Comment: Its not custom subclass initiation at all... Its just in Swift... Its made up out of so much rules and stuff... So its much easier to just init all properties at decleration time... But thats just my opinion to Swifts init rules... Anywhere else... its ok :-)

Comment: No you don't need to... Its just about every convenience init must call a designated init... So the easiest way to solve this, is the one above... All other inits are handled by Swift (automatically)...

Comment: Bitteschön, ein deutscher am Start hier oder was? :-)

Comment: Ich lernte Deutsch für ein Jahr im ersten Jahr im College. Und ich werde Deutschland besuchen im nächsten Jahr.